# StructClear and StructDelete do not work on IE8

Tags: session, coldfusion, internet-explorer-8

I have a situation where I wish to delete session variable on INITIAL entry to the page.

I'm trying to achieving it like this (JavaScript: `SetNextPage()` will set `hidSection` to a page name like `"PAGEONE"` or `"PAGETWO"`)

```
<!--- If INIT page access, it will be "" Otherwise it will not be "" --->
<cfset hidSection_val = "">
<cfif IsDefined("FORM.hidSection")>
    <cfset hidSection_val = FORM.hidSection>
</cfif>

<cfif hidSection_val eq "">
    <cfset tmp = StructClear(SESSION)>
    <cfset SESSION = StructNew()>
    <cfset hidSection_value = "PAGEONE">
<cfelse>
     <!--- Do other stuff --->
</cfif>
.
.
.
<input type="submit" name="btnAddToSession" id="btnAddToSession" value="Add" />
<input type="submit" name="btnNextPage" id="btnNextPage" value="Next Page" OnClick="SetNextPage()" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidSection" name="hidSection" value="#hidSection_value#">
```

I've omitted alot of code but I think I've laid out essencial ones up there.

So the steps I took:

1. Enter in form information then click Add button
2. Click on URL bar of the browser and press Enter

   Note: At this stage, I'd expect the code to run through StructClear etc.
3. I click on Next page button
4. I am able to CFDUMP the session variable with all the values in it.

Why is it displaying the session variables when I've cleared them?

FireFox and Chrome is working as expected. However, it does not work in IE8!

Is this an IE8 issue or do I have some sort of wrong idea of StructClear etc? Any ideas?

Comment: I think you need to revise your question title. `structClear()` and `structDelete()` *do* work: people use them every day and even based on your own situation, it's a bad description of the provlem. The issue here is that your logic is not doing what you're expecting it to (and as you say, possibly down to a quirk in IE8 which you need to work around). Have you put any debugging into your code to inspect for unexpected values, causing processing to follow an unexpected path through your code?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your comment. I've revised the title and bits in description. I tried debugging by CFDUMPing the session on initial page load and next page load. Weirdly, after taking above steps, it does not dump anything on initial page load but it dumps when I get to the next page. I am really puzzled!

Comment: "FireFox and Chrome is working as expected. However, it does not work in IE8!" Please make an educated guess.

Comment: Right, but how about verifying what's in the form scope, and accordingly whether the session-clear logic is even being called...

Comment: Yes, I have put a display string if it reaches the <cfif hidSection_val eq ""> scope and it did display it. Which means CF executed the structclear function. But accessing SESSION.Var[1].Name retrieves value that I've inserted before.

Comment: *"2. Click on URL bar of the browser and press Enter"* - Uhm... really? Who would do such a thing?

Comment: I do that all the time! :) I do that when I wish to start the page fresh without rePOSTing all the form values or any other data that might have derived to that point.

Comment: @James Ah, that makes sense. Misunderstanding on my side.

Comment: Bear in mind that ColdFusion code runs on the server and doesn't care about browswers.  I suggest that you start looking at the data that's being posted from your form.  Having two submit buttons could be problematic.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought.. especially with sessions without cookie. However it seems they are somehow related. Introducing cache expiry did stop session values coming back to the browser. Perhaps CF server setting has some weird session caching. I suppose I am using CF5!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, IE8 must have some sort of special caching thing.

Taking my chances, I tried this:

```
<form name="..." action="blah.cfm?n=<cfoutput>#Rand()#</cfoutput>" method="post">
```

and my Next page stopped picking up Sessions that were deleted/cleared!

Comment: Send appropriate caching headers (`Cache-Control`) instead of using cache breaking URLs.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak! I am using this solution now.